# Why does bookdown::render_book with output_format = pdf_book generate an error when output_format = "all" does not?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown, kable

I'm quite new to bookdown and trying to understand what is happening behind the scene when the following problem occurs.
I have created a reproducible example of my problem.
First i clone [bookdown-demo](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo).
Running the following command (`command A`) works as expected:

```r
bookdown::render_book(
    input = "index.Rmd",
    output_format = "bookdown::pdf_book", 
    output_dir = "_pdf")
```

If I change the content of the second chunk in `01-intro.Rmd` to

```r
library(kableExtra)
knitr::kable(
  head(iris, 20), caption = 'Here is a nice table!',
  booktabs = TRUE
) %>% 
  kableExtra::add_header_above( c(" ", "Group 1" = 1, "Group 2" = 3)) %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling(
      font_size = 10
    ) 
  kbl(mtcars[, 1:6], booktabs = T) %>%
kable_styling(latex_options = "striped") %>%
add_header_above(c(" ", "Group 1" = 2, "Group 2" = 2, "Group 3" = 2)) %>%
add_header_above(c(" ", "Group 4" = 4, "Group 5" = 2)) %>%
add_header_above(c(" ", "Group 6" = 6), bold = T, italic = T)
```

and issue the same command i get the following errormessage:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \cellcolor 

Error: LaTeX failed to compile bookdown-demo.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See bookdown-demo.log for more info.
```

If I instead issue the this command (`command B`):

```r
bookdown::render_book(
    input = "index.Rmd",
    output_format = "all")
```

it works.
It seem like `command A` fails to include (at least) the following lines in the .tex file and hence latex does not recognise some commands, but thats just my guess:

```latex
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

It further seems like `command A` works after restarting Rstudio but fails during the second run.
Can anyone explain why I get these error messages in such an arbitrarily manner and what is happening behind the scene?